# Html display issues

Tags: html, internet-explorer

Hope i can post this issue on this forum..
i have a page in php

http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/index.php

This displays fine in firefox and the new IE. but in any older version of IE its comes up all wroung!

please tell me what im doing wroung so that it disssplays incorrectly in old IE..
i wish to have a page that works in all browzers.. and i feel that is not to much to ask as html SHOULD be html and work correctly in every borwser that supports html...the php of the page still works fine as its server side.

in case you want the HTML code for the page here it is

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/frameset.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>
Welcome to ~Team Delta~ Starbase Home
</title>
<LINK REL="SHORTCUT ICON"
       HREF="/favicon.ico">

<META name="description" content="Team Delta welcomes you to it's forums, please don't hesitate to register and be a part of the community!">
<META name="keywords" content="astro, empire, astro empires, guild, clan, corporation, community, forum, vbulletin, game, fun, tactical, alliance, ally, member, online, illuminati, ascended">
<!-- CSS Stylesheet -->
<style type="text/css" id="vbulletin_css">
/**
* vBulletin 3.8.1 CSS
* Style: 'Charcoal'; Style ID: 2
*/
body
{
    background: #000000 url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/bodybg.jpg) repeat-x top;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}



.whatever {background-image: url('http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/theadbg.gif'); }


a:link, body_alink
{
    color: #f3ec84;
}
a:visited, body_avisited
{
    color: #f3ec84;
}
a:hover, a:active, body_ahover
{
    color: #f3ec84;
}


.page
{
    background: #1d1d1d;
    color: #EEEEEE;
}
td, th, p, li
{
    font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.tborder
{
    background: #000000;
    color: #f3ec84;
    border: 1px solid #444444;
}
.tcat
{
    background: #333333 url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/barbg.jpg) repeat-x top left;
    color: #f3ec84;
    font: bold 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    cell-spacing: 0px;
}
.tcat a:link, .tcat_alink
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tcat a:visited, .tcat_avisited
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.tcat a:hover, .tcat a:active, .tcat_ahover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.thead
{
    background: #444444 url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/theadbg.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font: bold 11px tahoma, verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-top: 1px solid #555555;
}
.tfoot
{
    background: #444444 url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/theadbg.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    border-top: 1px solid #555555;
}
.alt1, .alt1Active
{
    background: #3e3e3e;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
    border-top: 1px solid #4e4e4e;
    border-left: 1px solid #4e4e4e;
}
.alt2, .alt2Active
{
    background: #222222;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
    border-top: 1px solid #444444;
    border-left: 1px solid #444444;
}
.inlinemod
{
    background: #CCCCCC;
    color: #000000;
}
.wysiwyg
{
    background: #EEEEEE;
    color: #000000;
    font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    border: 0px;
}
textarea, .bginput
{
    background: #EEEEEE;
    font: 10pt verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.bginput option, .bginput optgroup
{
    font-size: 10pt;
    font-family: verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.button
{
    background: #b19a79;
    color: #000000;
    font: bold 10px verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
select
{
    font: 11px verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
option, optgroup
{
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.smallfont
{
    font: 11px verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.time
{
    font-size: 9px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.navbar
{
    font: 11px verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.highlight
{
    color: #FF0000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.fjsel
{
    background: #d3b994;
    color: #EEEEEE;
}
.fjdpth0
{
    background: #EEEEEE;
    color: #000000;
}
.panel
{
    background: #3e3e3e;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    border-top: 1px solid #555555;
    border-left: 1px solid #555555;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    border-right: 1px solid #000000;
    padding: 10px;
}
.panelsurround
{
    background: #222222;
    color: #EEEEEE;
}
legend
{
    color: #d3b994;
    font: bold 10px tahoma, verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
}
.vbmenu_control
{
    background: #4e4945 url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/barbg.jpg) repeat-x top left;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font: bold 11px tahoma, verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 3px 6px 3px 6px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.vbmenu_control a:link, .vbmenu_control_alink
{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vbmenu_control a:visited, .vbmenu_control_avisited
{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vbmenu_control a:hover, .vbmenu_control a:active, .vbmenu_control_ahover
{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
.vbmenu_popup
{
    background: #000000;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    border: 1px solid #444444;
}
.vbmenu_option
{
    background: #3e3e3e;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font: 11px verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.vbmenu_option a:link, .vbmenu_option_alink
{
    color: #d3b994;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vbmenu_option a:visited, .vbmenu_option_avisited
{
    color: #d3b994;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vbmenu_option a:hover, .vbmenu_option a:active, .vbmenu_option_ahover
{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vbmenu_hilite
{
    background: #222222;
    color: #EEEEEE;
    font: 11px verdana, geneva, lucida, 'lucida grande', arial, helvetica, sans-serif;
    white-space: nowrap;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.vbmenu_hilite a:link, .vbmenu_hilite_alink
{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vbmenu_hilite a:visited, .vbmenu_hilite_avisited
{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.vbmenu_hilite a:hover, .vbmenu_hilite a:active, .vbmenu_hilite_ahover
{
    color: #EEEEEE;
    text-decoration: none;
}
/* ***** styling for 'big' usernames on postbit etc. ***** */
.bigusername { font-size: 14pt; }

/* ***** small padding on 'thead' elements ***** */
td.thead, th.thead, div.thead { padding: 4px; }

/* ***** basic styles for multi-page nav elements */
.pagenav a { text-decoration: none; }
.pagenav td { padding: 2px 4px 2px 4px; }

/* ***** de-emphasized text */
.shade, a.shade:link, a.shade:visited { color: #777777; text-decoration: none; }
a.shade:active, a.shade:hover { color: #FF4400; text-decoration: underline; }
.tcat .shade, .thead .shade, .tfoot .shade { color: #DDDDDD; }

/* ***** define margin and font-size for elements inside panels ***** */
.fieldset { margin-bottom: 6px; }
.fieldset, .fieldset td, .fieldset p, .fieldset li { font-size: 11px; }
fieldset { border: 1px solid #555555; }

/* ***** don't change the following ***** */
form { display: inline; }
label { cursor: default; }
.normal { font-weight: normal; }
.inlineimg { vertical-align: middle; }
.underline { text-decoration: underline; }
html,body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   height: 100%;
   border: none
}
</style>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="clientscript/vbulletin_important.css?v=381" />



<!-- / CSS Stylesheet -->

</head>
<body>

<table border="0" width="90%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/header.jpg) repeat-x top;">
<tr>
    <td width="25" style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/header_l.jpg) no-repeat top left;"></td>

    <td align="left"><a href="index.php"><img src="http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/logo.jpg" border="0" alt="Team Delta Starbase Board" /></a></td>
    <td align="right" class="tfoot" style="background: none; border: 0px;">
    <div style="height: 3px;"></div>
    <div class="smallfont" style="height: 20px; font-weight: bold;">

<!-- TOP LINKS -->
    <a href="http://astroempires.com/index.aspx">Astro Empires</a> -
    <a href="http://wiki.astroempires.com/">Wiki</a> -
    <a href="http://delta.astroempires.com/home.aspx">Delta</a> -
    <a href="http://delta.astroempires.com/guild.aspx">Guild</a>



<!-- /TOP LINKS -->

    </div>
    <div align="right" class="page" style="height: 77px; background: none;">

    <br /><br />
    <b><font size="4">Welcome To Team Delta's Home page</font></b>
    </div>
    </td>
    <td width="25" style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/header_r.jpg) no-repeat top right;"></td>
</tr>




</table>
<table class="page" border="0" width="90%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" style="height: 100%;">
<tr>
<td style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/tdl.jpg) repeat-y left;"><img src="http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/spacer.gif" width="25" height="1" alt=""></td>
<td valign="top" width="100%">
</form>
<br>

<!--me-->


<div id="Marquee1" style="position:absolute;left:10%;top:96px;width:80%;height:20px;background-color:#1d1d1d;z-index:0">
<marquee direction="left" height="20" scrolldelay="10" scrollamount="4" behavior="scroll" loop="0" style="background-color:#1d1d1d;" id="Marquee1"><font style="font-size:13px" color="#f3ec84" face="Arial">

<div align="center" class="page" style="height: 10px; background: none;">
<font color=red>~Awaiting Attention~ Log in to Admin Panel to Change Text </font>
</div>
</font></marquee></div>





<!--navlink-->
<table border="1" bordercolor="#444444"  width="100%" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="1" align="center" >
<tr>
<td style="background: #000000; border: 0px; bordercolor: #444444;">

<table border="0" bordercolor="#444444" Background="#000000" height="50pt" width="100%" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="1" align="center" >
<tr style="background: #000000; border: 1px;">

<td style="background: #444444;">
<left><b><font color="white"><strong>&nbsp; &nbsp; &raquo;Team Delta Starbase</strong></font></b></left>
</td>
</tr>
</table>

<!--tableheader2-->
<table border="0" bordercolor="#444444" Background="#000000" width="100%" cellpadding="1"  cellspacing="1" align="center" >
<tr  height="20pt" style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/barbg.jpg) repeat-x top; border: 1; bordercolor: #444444;">
<td>
<left><b>
    <font color="white" size="2">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <a href="http://delta.astroempires.com/index.php">Home</a> &nbsp - &nbsp

    <a href="http://teamdelta.byethost12.com/cmps_index.php">Forum</a> &nbsp - &nbsp
    <a href="http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/resources.php">Admin Panel</a>
    </font>

</b></left>   <!--links here-->
</td>
</tr>
</table>



</td>
</tr>
</table>

<br>


<!--/navlink-->
<!--form1-->

<table border="1" bordercolor="#444444"  width="50%" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" align="left" >
<tr>
<td style="background: #000000; border: 0px; bordercolor: #444444;">

<table border="0" bordercolor="#444444" Background="#000000" width="100%" cellpadding="1"  cellspacing="1" align="left" >
<tr style="background: #000000; border: 0px;">
<td style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/barbg.jpg) repeat-x top;">
<center><b><font color="#f3ec84">&raquo;Guild Information&laquo;</font></b></center>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" class="tfoot" style="background: #222222; border: 0px;">
    <div align="left" class="page" style="height: 336px; background: none;">
    <br>
    <center>

    <table width="250" height="188" border="0"cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" BORDERCOLOR="#444444" style="background: url(http://delta.astroempires.com/images/avantars/guilds/134_1792989.jpeg);">
    <td>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    </td>
    </table>
    <br>
    Tag: [~TD~]
    <br>

    Guild #: 134
    <br>
    Guild Master: Astro
    <br>
    Guild Created: 18 November 2007
    <br>
    For Additional information please redirect <a href="http://delta.astroempires.com/guild.aspx?guild=134">Here</a>.
    <br>
    </center>

    </div>
</tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>

<!--/form1-->

<!--form2-->
<table border="1" bordercolor="#444444"  width="48%" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" align="right" >
<tr>
<td style="background: #000000; border: 0px; bordercolor: #444444;">

<table border="0" bordercolor="#444444" Background="#000000" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" align="right" >
<tr><td style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/barbg.jpg) repeat-x top;">
<b><font color="#f3ec84"><center>&raquo;Announcements&laquo;</center></b>

</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="right" class="tfoot" style="background: #222222; border: 0px;">
    <div align="center" class="page" style="height: 134px; background: none;">
<center><b>Recruitment status:</b><br>Accepting Recruits, Active, Willing To Learn, Veterans,<BR><B>Noobs Recruitment Status: <font color="green">Open</B><br>Active Players </font><br><br><font color=red><b>~Awaiting Attention~ <BR>Log in to Admin Panel to Change Text </b></font></center>    </div>
</tr>

</table>

</td></tr></table>
<!--/form2-->

<!--form3-->
<table border="0"  bordercolor="#444444"  width="48%" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" align="right" >   <!--invisible-->
<tr>
<td>

<br>

<table border="1" bordercolor="#444444"  width="100%" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" align="right" >
<tr>
<td style="background: #000000; border: 0px; bordercolor: #444444;">

<table top="500" border="0" bordercolor="#444444" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" align="right" height="184px">
<tr><td style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/barbg.jpg) repeat-x top;">
<b><font color="#f3ec84"><center>&raquo;Diplomatic status&laquo;</center></font></b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" class="tfoot" style="background: #222222; border: 0px;">
    <div align="center" class="page" style="height: 152px; background: none;">
Brother guild <a href="http://delta.astroempires.com/guild.aspx?guild=4325">[ROT] Reapers Of Time</a><br><br>

<font color=red><b>~Awaiting Attention~ <BR>

Log in to Admin Panel to Change Text </b></font>    </div>
</tr>
</table>

</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
<!--/form3-->

<!--form4-->

<table border="0" bordercolor="#444444"  width="100%" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" align="center" >   <!--invisible-->
<tr>
<td>

<br>

<table border="1" bordercolor="#444444"  width="100%" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" align="center" >
<tr>
<td style="background: #000000; border: 0px; bordercolor: #444444;">

<table top="60" border="0"  bordercolor="#000000" width="100%" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1" align="center" >
<tr>
<td bordercolor="#444444" style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/barbg.jpg) repeat-x top;">
<b><font color="#f3ec84"><center>&raquo;News&laquo;</center></font></b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="right" class="tfoot" style="background: #222222; border: 0px;">
    <div align="center" class="page" style="height: 157px; background: none;">

<strong>Welcome to Team Delta's Website! This site is still under construction but the <a href="cmps_index.php">forums</a> are up and running with ongoing refinements! Please Bookmark this page and register in the forums. Guild and Alliance members welcome in the forum.<br>Keahi and DarkLink.</strong>
    </div>
</tr>
</table>

</td></tr></table>
</td></tr></table>
<!--/form4-->

<!--Footnote-->
<br>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<left>
<font color="gold" size="1pt">Site Created by Keahi & Dark_Link</font>
</left>
<!--/Footnote-->






</td>
<!--/me-->

<!--left boder-->
<td style="background: url(http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/tdr.jpg) repeat-y right;"><img src="http://www.teamdelta.byethost12.com/forum/images/charcoal/misc/spacer.gif" width="25" height="1" alt=""></td>
</tr>
</table>




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That’s not a PHP issue. PHP is just composing the data sent to the client. But the ouput is the same for every browser (unless you’re using some browser sniffing to deliver the IE something special).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Arthur, in order for us to help, please replace the php code with an actual "rendering" of the HTML that is generated by this page. Simply open up the page in any browser and select "View Page Source" or similar and then paste that..

It would also help if you removed any parts of that rendered HTML that don't contribute in any way to the problem.. i.e. the page exhibits the same behavior/problems with or without those parts in it. That will reduce the time we'd have to spend looking for your problem.

In fact I suggest that you do this first before asking for help here. Try to narrow down the problem to a combination of HTML elements and styles that generate the odd behavior and then try making corrections (or seeking help on how to correct the specific issues that you found).

Unfortunately not all browsers are created equal..

Comment: Also state what you mean by "coming up all wrong" it will help us help you :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply, yes your last comment sums it all up really .. the problems lies with IE as it does not stick to standards and thus creates problems.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to help - maybe it will help and maybe it wont.  Tables are out of fashion these days.

But there's a lot of stuff going on in that html sample.  You have tables already, so what's one more, right?

I would try this:
Add a wrapping table.  and structure it this way:

> `   <table>
>   <tr>
>   <td>
>   put here the table with heading of guildinformation
>   </td><td>
>   put here the table with heading of anouncements 
>   and 
>   the table with heading of diplomatic status

</td>
</tr>
</table>`